# R: tar the command from the utils package doesn't seem to work in Windows?

Tags: r

I am trying a simple function tar to try and put a few files together under Windows.

```
tar("c:/testing/test.tar", "a_file.csv")
```

But c:/testing/test.tar only becomes a 1k file even though a_file.csv is a large csv? It is because tar is not supported in Windows? Or I need to install Rtools (which is not allowed on the my corporate computer).

Comment: You would need Cygwin (which is what rtools use) or MSYS. Not all is lost. See http://superuser.com/questions/244703/how-can-i-run-the-tar-czf-command-in-windows

Comment: Related to Roman's info: check out the argument at `?tar` named "tar" , which is used to provide the path to the operating system's "tar" command.